# Resources on Data Science for Football / Soccer?

Tags: data-mining, reference-request, sports

I am searching for resources on data science projects which used football/soccer data.

Comment: Check http://opendata.stackexchange.com/ and https://www.reddit.com/r/datasets

Comment: And where have you already searched? What projects have you already found? What do *you* mean by "data science project", because I know loads and loads of **statistical** projects that use soccer data, but maybe they aren't whatever *you* call "data science". Expand.

Answer (score 5):

1. There's this website called [Sportsdatamart](http://sportsdatamart.com/category/football/) which allows you to
   download CSV and XLS file formats for a number of Football series
   like the England Premier League, the Italian Serie A, the German
   Bundesliga and the Spanish La Liga.
2. On [Football Data UK](http://www.football-data.co.uk/downloadm.php), you can find EXCEL and CSV data files to
   use for quantitative testing of betting systems in spreadsheet
   applications. League tables, head2head statistics and information on
   goalscrores, first scorers and top scorers could be accessed through
   the [Livescore](http://livescore.football-data.co.uk/) service.
3. [Soccer Wiki](http://en.soccerwiki.org/wiki.php) is a collaborative database and anyone can create
   and edit data. This community driven database contains information
   on players, clubs, stadiums, managers, referees, leagues and other
   data related to the world of soccer.
4. If you are looking for data sets centered on European Football,
   check [this](http://www.quora.com/Where-can-I-download-a-database-with-european-football-matches-data) out.

Answer (score 3):

Check out the Github repositories for Christopher Long (octonion):

Football:

- https://github.com/octonion/football-public
- https://github.com/octonion/football

Soccer:

- https://github.com/octonion/soccer-m
- https://github.com/octonion/soccer

Many others:

- https://github.com/octonion?tab=repositories

Answer (score 1):

http://danielweitzenfeld.github.io/passtheroc/blog/2014/10/28/bayes-premier-league/ uses a bayesian approach on data taken from wikipedia (You can use any source in fact.)

It uses the following paper:

http://www.statistica.it/gianluca/Research/BaioBlangiardo.pdf
Bayesian hierarchical model for the prediction of football/soccer results

Answer (score 0):

Look at http://openfootball.github.io/ there are a lot of data for soccer South, North America, Europe and Asian is included